# ImageViewTouch become unable to Scale after setting it's scale type into CenterCrop

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Has anyone got the same problem of mine? When I run `imageVT.setScale(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)`
in an activity, it turns out that the image inside did fit the imageView frame but it became unable to scroll or to scale as well.

Comment: Scaletype=mattrix only work for scrolling..
I know in this case your image came at top right corner for this you have to wright custom code..

Comment: @ManishSrivastava yeah, I've headed of that, but I wonder how to rewrite its custom code without causing other problems. I hope someone could help.

Comment: I have working code...

Answer (score 0):

try this in my app  same problem i fix it ....

> android:scaleType="fitXY"